# US8598823 - Fan drive system for cooling tower is not novel

Tags: prior-art-request, us8598823

PM motors on a variety of applications has been done for 10 years. Cooling towers, fluid coolers, etc. The motor cost has not allowed it to go mainstream due to rare earth cost for the magnets.

Claim 1

> 1. A drive system for rotating a fan in a wet cooling tower, comprising
>
>    a permanent magnet motor comprising a motor casing,
>
>    a stator and
>
>    a rotatable shaft configured for connection to a fan in a wet cooling tower, the motor further comprising
>
>    a dual bearing system comprising a pair of bearings that locate and support the rotatable shaft relative to the motor casing, the drive system further comprising
>
>    sensors for measuring vibrations of the bearings and outputting signals representing the measured vibrations, and
>
>    sensors for measuring heat of the stator and the bearings and outputting signals representing the measured heat.

Answer (score 1):

Vibration and heat sensors is industry best practices in many installations today. That does not bring anything new to cooling systems. Simply substituting a different type of motor makes no difference in the functionality of the machine. In fact, that is a standard part of my work, upgrading old machines with newer technology, including better, previously overly expensive motors.

This patent is overly obvious to any practitioner in the field of machine automation.